# Problema com margin-left no Internet Explorer

Tags: css

A minha área nem é CSS, aprendi esses dias o básico e estou apenas quebrando um galho aqui.

O meu problema é com o `margin-left` de um botão, no Chrome ele fica na posição correta mas quando entro pelo Internet Explorer ele recua para esquerda alguns *pixels*:

No Google Chrome:
<kbd>[image: Google Chrome]</kbd>

No Internet Explorer:
<kbd>[image: Internet Explorer]</kbd>

O botão no XHTML:

```jsf
<div class="titulo">Você está no</div>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{MBTemplate.indexAtual == '/index_publico.xhtml'}">
    <div class="card-container"
         onclick="location.reload();
                  location.href = 'index_privado.xhtml'"
         onmouseover="javascript: rotacionarIconeDireita();"
         onmouseout="javascript: rotacionarIconeEsquerda();">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="side">Setor Público</div>
            <div class="side back">Ir ao Setor Privado</div>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/img/mudar_setor.gif" class="icone" id="icone" />
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{MBTemplate.indexAtual == '/index_privado.xhtml'}">
    <div class="card-container"
         onclick="location.reload();
                  location.href = 'index_publico.xhtml'"
         onmouseover="javascript: rotacionarIconeDireita();"
         onmouseout="javascript: rotacionarIconeEsquerda();">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="side">Setor Privado</div>
            <div class="side back">Ir ao Setor Público</div>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/img/mudar_setor.gif" class="icone" id="icone" />
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

CSS:

```
.titulo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 61px;
    width: 100px;
}

.icone {
    margin-left: 107px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.card-container {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
    perspective: 600;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.card {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.card:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card .side {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eaeaed;
    color: #0087cc;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .back {
    background: #eaeaed;
    color: #0087cc;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Porque as tags java e java-ee?

Comment: Ele não me parece estar a recuar aqui neste exemplo no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rf2k9qjh/

Comment: Qual internet-explorer?

Comment: Coloquei tais tag pois java faz parte da minha aplicação, mas acho que fiz cagada , mas tudo bem kk

Comment: Guilherme, testei no IE 8 e 9.

Comment: Tentei usar % e em , mas o problema persiste , se alguém puder me ajudar por favor, e de vital importância

Comment: @Chun, no exemplo do jsfiidle, acessando aqui com o chrome, recuou.. Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Falta definir os elementos para serem exibidos como `inline`. Para isso, utilize o parâmetro `display`. Exemplo: `display:inline`.
Contudo, caso queira customizar margens e espaçamentos (padding, margin), defina como `display:inline-block`.

**2.** A largura do estilo `.card` está em `100%`, logo, mesmo que os elementos estejam com `display:inline-block`, serão jogados para baixo devido também a definição de largura fixa no container principal `.card-container`, definido com `200px`.

Para resolver, defina uma lagura fixa para o estilo `.card`. Na correção abaixo, foi definido como `130px`.

**3.** Nos estilos `.icone`, `.card-container` and `.card`, defina o parâmetro `position` como `relative`.

**4.** No estilo `.icone`, remova o parâmetro `margin-left`.

**Veja o resultado abaixo:**

```
.titulo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 61px;
    width: 100px;
}

.icone {
    margin-top: 3px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.card-container {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50px;
    perspective: 600;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display:block;
}

.card {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    width: 130px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

.card:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card .side {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eaeaed;
    color: #0087cc;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.card .back {
    background: #eaeaed;
    color: #0087cc;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Apenas troque toda a parte CSS por essa correção. Na parte HTML, não precisa mexer em nada, apesar de ter diversos erros também.

Apenas troque o CSS pela correção e veja o resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa colocar a declaração `!DOCTYPE` na primeira linha de sua página:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Não funcionou amigo :(